# Trouble with <input> styling and autofill

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, input

I am building a login modal and would like to use input tags to enable browsers to autocomplete username and password however I am struggling to fully reset the User Agent Stylesheet styling for input tags. Whenever autocomplete does its thing the old styling comes back.

Here's my (simplified) react login form:

```html
<form id="login-popup-container">
    <div className="login-field-container">
        <div className="login-value-title user">email</div>
        <input className="answer login-info" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div className="login-field-container">
        <div className="login-value-title password">password</div>
        <input className="answer login-info" type="password" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I have added this in my index.css:

```css
input, input:focus, input:active, input:hover, input:-webkit-autofill, input:autofill, input:indeterminate, input:enabled, input:valid {
    outline: none !important;
    border:none !important;
    background-image:none !important;
    background-color:transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

It works in a chrome **incognito** browser [well enough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5fJb.jpg)

But in a **regular** chrome tab when autofill is performed by chrome this action brings the User Agent Stylesheet styling back to the input elements [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAMpc.jpg). As you can see above I have tried adding all the pseudo classes I could think of to the input tag reset styling but with no success.

Has anybody experienced this issue before / know why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody experiencing this issue... the answer to my question turned out to be a combination of Zach Jensz's answer and adding a transition delay to `<input>` elements. It's definitely more of a hack than an answer, but for me it works.

My css reset looks like this:

```
input {
  all: unset;
}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active {
  transition: all 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

and my styling for inputs looks like this:

```
.classname-used-for-my-inputs {
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

The reason the delay hack is necessary is because even after unsetting all the styles, upon an autocomplete of the email/password event the User Agent styles kept coming back (I could not figure out how to prevent this). But at least now the delay time is so long that for all practical purposes no one will ever notice them and so for my purposes it works.

If somebody explains why / proposes a non hacky solution I will update this.

Comment: The solution to why is this working is you cannot override the browser's autofill styles. But you can create a **long enough transition** from your custom styles to the browser's styling. So if you waited 5000 seconds you would see the autofill styles. 


In your example you're setting the transition time, not the delay, so it would be better to have `transition: all 0s 5000s;` which delays the transition.
When searching I found the same solution in other places too, so this seems a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't override UA styles with !important**

> The user agent style sheets of many browsers use !important in their :-webkit-autofill style declarations, making them non-overrideable by webpages without resorting to JavaScript hacks.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill

Also, more efficiently reset every single style on your inputs with the CSS `all` property!

```css
input {
  all: unset;
}
```

You can use these global values:

- *initial* - set all properties to property default defined by CSS
- *unset* - if normally inherited: inherit, if not: initial
- *revert* - set all properties to default for element defined by UA

Comment: Thanks Zach, very helpful! This seems to work great under normal conditions but upon an autocomplete event by chrome browser (email/password) the UA styles keep coming back.

Comment: @pr0grara That's what I'm saying - the browser will override ANYTHING you try and do with your author styles, this is why the important keyword is so hated. Importance runs: browser styles --> user styles --> author styles --> important author styles --> important user styles --> important browser styles. Without JS hacks which I do not recommend, it's impossible to override.

Answer (score 0):

Also for styled-components, you could only apply it in your global.styles folder

```
input {
  all: unset;
}
```